# Analysis of experiment without using MANOVA

Tags: hypothesis-testing, spss, multiple-comparisons

My dissertation topic is on differences in body image in different dance and different skill levels. My IV is dance type (Dancehall, Street, Contemporary, Ballet, Other and non-dancer) my DV's are 5 different scale measures of body image. An additional IV is skill level (nominal) and Years Trained (scale).

Which would be the easiest and clearest way of running this analysis? I sort of want to avoid MANOVA and I am not very talented with SPSS.

Comment: What to do in SPSS is off-topic here: please see the Help Center on what is on-topic. If you are asking how best to analyse scale measures of body image in terms of other variables, then you may need tell us more about those measures to get good advice. Don't you have one or more advisors/supervisors?

Comment: @NickCox, the "in SPSS" seems ancillary here. I think this is a straightforward 'what test' question.

Comment: @gung I tend to agree, despite the question title and closing sentence,  which is why I suggested adding more on the outcome variables (DVs in the OP's terms).

Answer (score 2):

If I am reading correctly, you have a pretty straightforward design, which could be analyzed in a multiple regression/general linear model (GLM) framework, using both the categorical variables (type of dance and skill level) as well as the 'years training' continuous variable as predictors. One way of handling the multiple DVs would be to just run the model separately for each outcome (its not the "best" analysis/idea but it would work, especially if you use an alpha adjustment over all the tests you do). 
Each analysis answers a different question - make sure you clearly phrase your research questions - all of them - explicitly. This always guides analysis. For example, you may want to know "Does the type of dance predict body image (measured using test C) all other variables being constant?, " vs "Does type of dance interact with skill level to predict body image (measured using test A?)"

Write out each of your potential questions as clearly as possible, exhausting all the questions you want to answer. Then think about which analyses will answer them, one by one. Use an alpha adjustment to control for multiple tests.